# Searching More Table Than One At Once To Find Value

Tags: php, mysql, authentication

I'm trying to finish my login function on my app but am having trouble with finishing it up. I had to split the `users` with the `reps` into two different tables. When the account for either of these is created, I double check to see if the username exits already in both tables so there is no duplicate username.

When it comes to my login function I know I am just getting the query incorrect because it works just fine if I only search ONLY the user table and try to log in with a user that lives in that user table. I want to look through BOTH tables at the same time but I am getting errors on the following query:

```
public function login($username, $password){
// Find the username if it exists
$user = $this->fetch_array("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='{$username}' UNION SELECT * FROM reps WHERE username='{$username}'");
// Kill the query if the username is not found
if(!$user){
  session_unset();
  $_SESSION["message"] = "Username/Password not found.";
  $_SESSION["message-color"] = "red";
}
// If username is found, verify if the password is correct
if(password_verify($password, $user["password"])) {
  // If password is correct, set our `$_SESSION` variables
  // Then redirect to selected page
  $_SESSION['current_user'] = $user['username'];
  $_SESSION['current_user_id'] = $user['id'];
  $_SESSION['current_user_role'] = $user['role'];
  switch ($_SESSION['current_user_role']) {
    case "administrator":
      redirect_to("mod-administrator/");
    break;
    case "manager":
      redirect_to("mod-manager/");
    break;
    case "representative":
      redirect_to("mod-representative/");
    break;
  }
}else{
  // If password is not correct just return false and stay on login page and unset the session;
  session_unset();
  $_SESSION['message'] = 'Username/Password not found';
  $_SESSION['message-color'] = 'red';
}
}
```

Maybe I am not using 'UNION' the correct way? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What error are you getting ? And are those tables have the same columns? If there is not the same number of columns mysql will throw an error about it.

Comment: database query failed. so I know it's going on in that `$user` variable setup. Cause it works just fine if I change the SQL statement to `"SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='{$username}'"` instead of having that UNION in there

Comment: please specify the structure of both tables

Answer (score 1):

When you use a `UNION`, both sub-queries have to select the same number of columns, and the equivalent columns should be in the same place in the list, since the column names will come from the `SELECT` list of the first query. You should change your query so you just select the specific columns you need, which are in both tables.

```
$user = $this->fetch_array("SELECT id, username, role, password FROM users WHERE username='{$username}' 
                            UNION 
                            SELECT id, username, role, password FROM reps WHERE username='{$username}'");
```

If, as I suspect, there's no `role` column in the `users` table, you need to put a placeholder there.

```
$user = $this->fetch_array("SELECT id, username, 'user' AS role, password FROM users WHERE username='{$username}' 
                            UNION 
                            SELECT id, username, role, password FROM reps WHERE username='{$username}'");
```

A better overall design would be to have the login information for both users and reps in the `users` table. The `reps` table would just have the additional information for reps, with a foreign key to the `users` table for the login details. You could then use a `LEFT JOIN`

```
SELECT u.id, u.username, IFNULL(r.role, 'user') role, u.password
FROM users AS u
LEFT JOIN reps AS r ON u.id = r.user_id
```